# $A^{1\over A} = B^{1\over B} = C^{1\over 3} $ and $ A^{BC}+B^{AC}+C^{AB}=729 $ Find the value of $A^{1\over A}$

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

$$A^{1\over A} = B^{1\over B} = C^{1\over 3} $$ 
and 
$$ A^{BC}+B^{AC}+C^{AB}=729 $$
Find the value of A^{1\A}.

What I tried doing -
$$ A^{1\over A} = B^{1\over B} = C^{1\over 3} = k $$
$$ => A = k^A $$
$$ => B = k^B $$
$$ => C = k^3 $$

I tried substituting the values in the 2nd equation but that didn't lead me anywhere.
$$A^{1\over A} = C^ {1\over 3} $$
$$ => A = C^{A\over3}$$
$$ => B =  C^{B\over3}$$
$$ => AB = C^{A+B\over3}$$
Tried doing this as well but still didn't look right. Am I on the right track? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Is it $C^{1/C}$ or $C^{1/3}$?

Comment: According to my book it's $C^{1\over3} $ although it might be a misprint.

Comment: Then you don't have $C=k^C$.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry my bad. :p

Comment: Numerically, $A = B \approx 2.264065981110338, C \approx 2.952879167935156$ is a solution with $A^{1/A} \approx 1.434658575619224$ However, this number doesn't seem to have any simple closed form... There may be another solution with $A < e < B$ but haven't figure out a way to compute it (even numerically).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that $$A^{1/A}=B^{1/B}=C^{1/C}=t$$ then we get using the second equation
$$3t^{ABC}=729$$ therefore $$t^{ABC}=3^4$$
can you finish?

Comment: :Are you suppose that $C^{\dfrac1C}$ ?

Comment: yes indeed that have i assumed

Comment: Although using $C^{1/C}$ would make the problem a lot simpler (and more esthetic), the fact is that there is no real reason to assume that this is so. The OP himself has double checked that it is indeed $C^{1/3}$ and not $C^{1/C}$ in the original problem, and it's well-known that not all problems are symmetrically constructed. However, if it does turn out to be a typo, this is a good way to go about solving the presumed intended problem.